# Formula for checking if a Visio ShapeSheet section is empty

Tags: hyperlink, visio, shapesheet

I need an action in the shape context menu to be enabled only when there is at least one hyperlink (the "Hyperlinks" section is non-empty).

Is there a formula for this?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean a formula for testing if there are any hyperlinks try:

```
    If (vsoShape.RowCount(visSectionHyperlink) > 0) Then
        'Code to enable context menu
    End If
```